# Ajax Helper not redrawing the form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use `Ajax.BeginRouteForm` to create a list of results that can be paged and searched. The general idea is that the menu at the top of view and the layout would not be redrawn, but the central area with the search results would be.

So I have two controller actions, a GET, which returns an initial model and the view, and a POST, which takes the model, gets the page/search info from it, and runs the search, returning the same model and view.

What I'm seeing is that the POST works, the new results are obtained, and the view is being compiled with those new results (debug code tells me this), but clientside the form is not being redrawn.

When I add the InsertionMode and UpdateTargetId params, I get the view-inside-the-view issue, where the whole menu is being rendered inside the form area.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm(ContentRoutes.EmailContentList,
    new { instance = UserContext.InstanceId },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "blockForm();",
        OnComplete = "unblockForm();",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "frmContent"
    },
    new { id = "frmContent" }))
```

{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an outside div with `ID` `frmContent` containing the form

```
<div id="frmContent">
    @using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm(ContentRoutes.EmailContentList,
        new { instance = UserContext.InstanceId },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnBegin = "blockForm();",
            OnComplete = "unblockForm();",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "frmContent"
        }
    }
</div>
```

This is because you are adding the result of the AJAX call to the frmContent HTML element.

Also, you should make sure that *AJAX* actually works: Use `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` inside your *Action* and inspect it's value with the *debugger*.

Comment: this solves the issue of not re-drawing, but it still has the view-inside-a-view issue. I think I was expecting behavior similar to an UpdatePanel where the whole view comes back from the server, but only that one section is redrawn.

Comment: Please try having <div id="frmContent"> inside the View that's rendered.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I still get the HTML from outside the form rendered into the form. In your solution do you have a GET and POST actions that both return the same view?

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that AJAX works? what you're describing seems to sound a lot like your form is doing a complete POST instead of an AJAX call. This is easy to check, use `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` in your Action and debug.

Comment: Ok, no idea why it was not working this morning, but it is working now. thanks!